# How to return the numbers back to the string as reversed

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I'm working on the practice and I got an example of how the program works

```
Entry: "Dlasdf234dkl sdfkl8886adaf15adfjk7 asdflkj376661a s445s198"

Output: "Dlasdf432dkl sdfkl6888adaf51adfjk7 asdflkj166673a s544s891"
```

I managed to get all the numbers regardless of where they are, and I did that by explode and implode. I have numbers as strings and because I did it in a loop, I am stuck and can't get numbers back in original string.

When I try to put them back in string I get this mess:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf432dkl sdfkl432adaf432adfjk432 asdflkj432a s432s432
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf6888dkl sdfkl6888adaf6888adfjk6888 asdflkj6888a s6888s6888
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf51dkl sdfkl51adaf51adfjk51 asdflkj51a s51s51
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf7dkl sdfkl7adaf7adfjk7 asdflkj7a s7s7
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf166673dkl sdfkl166673adaf166673adfjk166673 asdflkj166673a s166673s166673
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf544dkl sdfkl544adaf544adfjk544 asdflkj544a s544s544
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [a] => Dlasdf891dkl sdfkl891adaf891adfjk891 asdflkj891a s891s891
        [sub] => Пошаљи
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use regex to parse out the numbers and replace them:

```
<?php

$str = 'Dlasdf234dkl sdfkl8886adaf15adfjk7 asdflkj376661a s445s198';


echo preg_replace_callback('~([0-9]{2,})~', function($matches) { return strrev($matches[1]); }, $str);
// Dlasdf432dkl sdfkl6888adaf51adfjk7 asdflkj166673a s544s891

?>
```

Comment: Tnx man your help is goods blessing omg i cant belive it was that eazy